# CSS : Fix two corners with transform

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an hover animation on my menu. I use "transform" on hover. 
I have an issue, I would like to fix the left and right top corner of my div. I don't want to have then be move during the transform.
The effect I would like to have is an open box effect. 
Right now, I am close to have the effect. I just need to fix the top corners and to make the shadow disappear smoothy when the hover is finished.
Could you help me ?

https://jsfiddle.net/Goby03/28fpk45h/

```css
[class*="col-"] {
   width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
   /* For tablets: */
   .col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
   .col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
   .col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
   .col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
   .col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
   .col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
   .col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
   .col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
   .col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
   .col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
   .col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
   .col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
   /* For desktop: */
   .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
   .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
   .col-3 {width: 25%;}
   .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
   .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
   .col-6 {width: 50%;}
   .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
   .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
   .col-9 {width: 75%;}
   .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
   .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
   .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
}

.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

/*nav*/


.menuPrincipal {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width : 100%;
}

.menuPrincipal ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: var(--menu-border-color);
}

.activeLink {
  color: yellow;
}

.menuPrincipal ul li a {
  display: block;
  color : white;
  transition: transform ease 2s;
  text-align: center;
}

.menuPrincipal ul li a div {
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-color: var(--menu-border-color);
  border-width: 2px;
  background: var(--menu-color);
  height : 3em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.menuPrincipal ul li a div p {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.menuPrincipal ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}



.menuPrincipal ul li a:hover {
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  color : white;
  text-align: center;
  /*transform-origin:  0 -100% ;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(-20deg) rotateX(40deg);*/
  transform: skewX(-25deg) translateX(-4%) translateY(10%) scaleY(1.2);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px #303030;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menuPrincipal row">
      <ul class="row">
        <li class="col-m-2">
          <a href="#" class="activeLink"><div class="activeDiv"><p>Accueil</p></div></a> 
        </li>
        <li class="col-m-2">
          <a href="#"><div><p>Bonnes pratiques de l'UX</p></div></a> 
        </li>
        <li class="col-m-2">
          <a href="#"><div><p>Nos domaines d'expertises</p></div></a> 
        </li>
        <li class="col-m-2">
          <a href="#"><div><p>Formation</p></div></a> 
        </li>
        <li class="col-m-2">
          <a href="#"><div><p>L'équipe</p></div></a> 
        </li>
        <li class="col-m-2">
          <a href="#"><div><p>Contact</p></div></a> 
        </li>
      </ul>

    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My answer and explanation**

When you are transforming DOM elements with CSS you should keep an eye on the movement/positioning of an element after the transformation is done. As Md. Abu Sayed stated, you'll have to reverse or prevent the movement of a transformed element to keep the element in place.

The only thing is that this is a half part of the answer to the question since you asked us also to include a smooth `transition` of the `box-shadow` when the `:hover` event is done.

I've updated your code by including the fix of Md. Abu Sayed and adding a `transition` on the `box-shadow` of the hyperlink inside the list item on `:hover`. I also saw that the styling of the `.activeLink` class was not shown, so I've moved and updated the selection of this class to get the style working.

Note that I only have included CSS code in the since that is my answer to your question. See my [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/28fpk45h/1/) for a full working example.

**Total solution**

```css
.menuPrincipal {
  position: fixed;
  width : 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.menuPrincipal ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: var(--menu-border-color);
}

.menuPrincipal ul li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menuPrincipal ul li:hover {
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.menuPrincipal ul li a {
  display: block;
  background: var(--menu-color);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.2s, box-shadow 0.2s;
}

.activeLink, .menuPrincipal ul li a.activeLink {
  color: yellow;
}

.menuPrincipal ul li:hover a {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px #303030;
  transform: skewX(-25deg) translateX(-11px) translateY(10%) scaleY(1.2);
  transition: transform 0.2s, box-shadow 0.4s;
}

.menuPrincipal ul li a div {
  position: relative;
  height : 3em;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-color: var(--menu-border-color);
  border-width: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menuPrincipal ul li a div p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain to me how I can calculate the position when I use skew ?

Comment: You can calculate the position on the X-axle as follows: Take the width of the skewed element minus the width of the non-skewed state of the element and divide that by two since the element is moving in one direction. The formula: `translateX = (skewedWidth - normalWidth) / 2`  But since you are using a `scale(1.2)` you also have to divide by `1.2` after calculating the aformentioned formula. So if you take example values of your jsFiddle the sum will be: `((165.36px - 138.5px) / 2) / 1.2 = 11.1916px`.  So that's how I would get the 11px from @Md. Abu Sayed's answer

Answer (score 3):

**you can try this:**

```
.menuPrincipal ul li a:hover {
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    transform: skewX(-25deg) translateX(-11px) translateY(10%) scaleY(1.2);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px #303030;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! But does it work with any screen resolution ?
And could you explain how you find the value of  "-11px" ? I would like to understand for the next time.

Comment: when you rotate element then top side move automatically 11px, in your rotate element. So, This is reverse of element behavior.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And this will work with any skewX value ?